# C: Create randomly-generated integers, store them in array elements, and print number of integers stored in each element

Tags: c, arrays, element, random-seed

I'm incredibly new to `C` (and programming in general) and finding how to manipulate arrays is almost impossible to understand (I know what an array is).

I'm attempting to write a program that generates **100 random integers** in a **range (1-50)**, stores them in array elements (1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, and 41-50), and print the number of randomly generated integers stored in each element, i.e.

- 1-10 = 20
- 11-20 = 30
- 21-30 = 21
- 31-40 = 19
- 41-50 = 20

The best I can come up with so far is:

```
void randomNumbers
{
    int count[ARRAY_LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        count[i] = rand() % 50 + 1;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= ARRAY_LENGTH - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("Index %d -> %d\n", i, count[i]);
    }
}
```

[image]

That just says "element 1 = random number, element 2 = random number" etc.

I don't understand how to:

- Store the randomly-generated integers in the array's elements
- Partition the randomly-generated integers into the corresponding
  element
- Tell the program to print the number of integers generated in each
  element range

Comment: Are you saying you have 5 bins, each of which is used to store numbers in its range? I can't see any other point in the grouping. Aside: `i <= ARRAY_LENGTH - 1;` is more idiomatic (and readable) as `i < ARRAY_LENGTH;`

Comment: If the random number, `r`, is in the range [1,50] and you then want to reduce the value with an expression that yields `0` when `r` is in the range 1..10, and yields 2 when `r` is in the range 11..20, etc, then `(r - 1) / 10` yields the correct result.  (For example, `r == 1; (r - 1) / 10 == 0;` — `r == 10; (r - 1) / 10 == 0;` — `r == 11; (r - 1) / 10 == 1;` — `r == 50; (r - 1) / 10 == 4;` — etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the code that generates 100 random integers and groups them into categories based on their value :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, temp;
  int a[5]; // array to store the frequency
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   a[i]=0;
  srand(time(0));  // for generating new random integers on every run
  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    temp = (rand()%50) + 1; // generates random integers b/w 1 to 50
    a[(temp-1)/10]++;
  }
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d->%d  = %d\n",i*10+1,(i+1)*10,a[i]); //printing in the desired format
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there any way I can adapt the code so I can change the ranges (e.g. 1-12, 13-20 etc.)?